# PHP ZipArchive fails on close without error message

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have implemented a PHP script which periodically adds some images to an existing zip archive. However, it crashes always when the zip archive exceeds 131Mb. I increased the memory_limit, max_input_time and and execution time, did not help. The problem seems to really be the archive's size. Somebody has a solution/explanation for this?

```
$valid_files = array('/path/to/file/a.png'); //Array of existing files
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ( $zip->open( $destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE ) !== true) {
        return false;
}
foreach ( $valid_files as $i => $file ) {
    $zip->addFile( $file, basename( $file ) );
}

if ( $zip->close() !== true ) {//close crashes the process if zip > 131Mb
    //PHP process is killed before reaching this
}
```

Comment: The PHP script is running on a one.com server.

Comment: You can edit your question to add relevant information rather than comment. Anyway, "131" is suspiciously close to a 128mio memory limit. Does your host actually allow you to set configuration options such as memory limit and execution time ? Try running `phpinfo()` after setting a new memory limit and see if the values match.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The memory_limit is set correctly as far as I can state, since the phpinfo function echoes a memory_limit of 256M after setting it. However, there are two columns 'local vars' and 'master vars'. The value of the master memory_limit variable is unchanged (128M). But this should not be a problem, right?

The zipping process is again killed at 131Mb.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether this would still happen if you did "open, add, close" in each iteration of the loop. Also, how many files do you add with this loop ?

Comment: Same thing happens when I put those operations in the loop. I tried it with different numbers of files and also different files, to be sure that it does not depend on some "broken" files. I also checked the permission, everything fine. So it does not make a difference if I put just one file in the array or 5, the process crashes at 131Mb.

Comment: How many files are in the zip when it crashes ? Could you try adding a lot of very small files (<1 kio) and check if it crashes at the same point ? Same with very large files (>10mio).

Comment: Tried this, same result: 131Mb -> crash.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas for now but I wonder if it could be a side effect of something unrelated to php or zip. This kind of size issue seems uncommon and it's presumably also not related to file descriptors as described on the [ZipArchive::addFile](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) doc page. I'll keep thinking about it though, it's rather interesting.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your PHP error reporting level? Is something to be seen in the log files? PHP doesn't normally crash without an error message.

Comment: Add this to the top of your script: ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Errors are enabled and error log file path is defined. No errors are logged (if I force an error it is written in the error log file, so no confusion possible here.)